Obtaining text responses from Alexa
I'm working on a project and I want to know if there is a way to get Alexa's answers in text on my computer. That is, if, for example, the answer that Alexa gives me to a question I ask her, I can somehow receive it on my PC as text, so that I can apply some processing to it.
I have found a way to send questions to the alexa echo device I have, and even send a text to the device to say it orally, but what I am looking for now is to be able to RECEIVE alexa's ANSWER to the question on my pc.
I've been trying to see if any Node-RED node already did this, and I've ended up researching Alexa's skills development, because I've read that I can find something there.
I don't know if I'm too far off the solution, but if anyone can shed some light on the matter, I'd appreciate it.
